# Error During Installation of Darknet on Windows

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, darknet

I couldn't find any good tutorial for installation of Darknet and Lightnet on Windows. However, following the tutorials on their official Git Page, I tried running Python command

```
pip install darknetpy
```

On running this, I am seeing the following error:

```
  Failed building wheel for darknetpy
  Running setup.py clean for darknetpy
Failed to build darknetpy
Installing collected packages: darknetpy
  Running setup.py install for darknetpy ... error
    Complete output from command c:\users\pop\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\Pop\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-aew1mvz2\\darknetpy\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\Pop\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-hj4a3ywj-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    running install
    running build
    running build_ext
    'make' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
    operable program or batch file.
    error: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified: 'C:\\Users\\Pop\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\darknet\\libdarknet.so'

    ----------------------------------------
Command "c:\users\pop\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\Pop\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-aew1mvz2\\darknetpy\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\Pop\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-hj4a3ywj-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\Pop\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-aew1mvz2\darknetpy\
```

Comment: Been there, man! To install Darknet on Windows the best thing to do is to use this fork: https://github.com/AlexeyAB/darknet . There you gotta build all the stuff through running a project in Visual Studio with C/C++ installed and, depending on what you wanna be installed, OpenCV & CUDA. If you have some time and still wanna figure things out, I've made an easy-to-follow video on that. Hope it helps! https://youtu.be/-HtiYHpqnBs

Answer (score 1):

Even with Cygwin(64), the issue [darknetpy issue 1](https://github.com/danielgatis/darknetpy/issues/1) shows it wouldn't work on Windows.

The best options are (on Windows):

- use a VM Linux
- use a docker image for darknet, like [`lindt/docker-darknet`](https://github.com/lindt/docker-darknet) (with [docker-for-windows](https://www.docker.com/docker-windows), which will use a small Linux VM through HyperV)

Answer (score 0):

The [pypi](https://pypi.python.org/pypi) page for [darketpy](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/darknetpy/2.0) indicates that it requires a POSIX operating system. If you want to install it on Windows, you'll need something like [cygwin](https://www.cygwin.com/).